# Using slice function to convert data.frame to numeric

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I noticed that thought using `dplyr` is quite handy when handling dataframe, sometimes when using `select` or `slice`, the resulting data.frame cannot be converted to `numeric`, in order to do subsequent analysis, such as linear regression.

Here is my simple codes, where I want to select the first 100 rows:

```
Y <- data.frame(rnorm(1000,0,1))
Y_used <- Y %>% slice_head( n = 100)
```

The vector `Y_used` is of `data.frame`, and the function `as.numeric()` seems not working.

If I still want to use `slice` to select it, how can I convert `Y_used` to `numeric`? Thanks!

Comment: If you want single column as numeric you can `pull` the data instead. `Y %>% pull(col_name)`.

Comment: @RonakShah I think ```pull``` is used to select columns. Here I wanna select the first 100 rows of a vector.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data along with expected output.

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, I have an example.

Comment: You have not shown your expected output. Also you didn't name the column in `df`. So if your dataframe is `Y <- data.frame(a  = rnorm(1000,0,1))`. Is `Y %>% slice_head( n = 100) %>% pull(a)` what you want?